# ¿Can you create a smart contract so it can receive ether from metamask platform?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I'm new to solidity development so maybe this isn't as difficult as it is right now for me. I created a smart contract that can receive and send ether to different accounts. If I connect ganache to metamask, I can see it changes the account balance when these functions are called. I use "send" method to send ether to an account and use a "depositToThisContract" function as payable to receive ether in the smart contract.

My question is **¿Is it possible for a smart contract to be written so it can receive ether directly from metamask platform?** That is without calling these functions through metamask API or using web3. Directly from metamask, just like you would send ether to any other account ¿Is there a class or other type of contract that I can import so my contract recognize transactions coming from metamask platform and updates the balance? ¿Or maybe override an existing default function?

Thanks

PS: This is my first question ever at a development forum. I would really appreciate if you could tell me how to make this better.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the special `receive` function ([docs)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#receive-ether-function). This function is executed when someone sends ETH to the contract without any data (i.e. they're not calling a function).

```
receive() external payable {
    // Do something here
}
```

This would trigger when someone sends ETH directly to the contract from Metamask without calling any functions